# DDEV - Setup PHP Intelephense on VSCode on a DDEV installed in WSL Ubuntu

Tags: php, ddev

I'm working in a project with DDEV, with VS Code, using WSL:Ubuntu.
Everything is working fine, but I need to use PHP Inteliphense plugin and I can't set it up.

I don't know where the php is installed on DDEV so I can copy and paste the PATH for the settings.json.

Comment: As far as I can tell [Inteliphense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) is a plugin for vscode, has nothing to do with ddev or where PHP lives in DDEV. (php is in the ddev-webserver, in /usr/bin/php, so `ddev exec php --version` for example.)

Does this require some PHP extension? If it does, you would add it with `webimage_extra_packages`.